# Custom Django Model Field (lazy encryption/decryption)

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a method that can be overridden that is only called when the field is loaded from the database.

I have an encrypted field from a legacy table, (that has no prefix, or identifying format that can be reliably used to determine if it is encrypted or not.)

My decryption code cannot go in the to_python function because it is called not only when loaded from the database.

To make things worse, I wanted to make the decryption and encryption lazy, so that I do not have to make calls to decrypt/encrypt unless it is required. (the encryption code is a weird flavor of AES in ASP classic, so I created an asp service that I can call from python. And it is painfully slow) I used django's lazy function to create a nice decrypt_lazy function but without being able to know if the value is encrypted or not I am stuck.

So to reiterate my main question is... is there a method or hook I can use on a custom model field that is used to process the value only when the value comes from the database. And again to_python does not work for me since it is called and passed values from other places.

Comment: It seems pretty crazy there is no method for this, because there are a bunch for the other direction (python -> database) [get_db_prep_save, get_db_prep_value and get_prep_value]

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a [`@property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) method when you need decrypted value of a field -

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @property
    def pin_decrypted(self):
        # decrypt self.pin and return
        return magic_decrypt_method(self.pin)
```

Now you can either access `person.pin` or `person.pin_decrypted`.

Comment: Okay this does solve my problem, but is not perfect. Fortunately my project has moved forward, and I will be able to move to a new encryption column where I can appropriately prefix the encrypted value. (I will mark this as the answer if no one else comes up with anything better)

Comment: Not sure what can be better than having both the encrypted and lazy decrypted value at your disposal. But sure.